# SQLAlchemy's UNION as CTE missing outer parentheses

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I try to use SQLAlchemy to generate a query like

```
WITH
_cte_a AS (SELECT x FROM some_table),
_cte_b AS (SELECT x FROM next_table),
_cte_c AS (
    SELECT x FROM _cte_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x FROM _cte_b)
SELECT *
FROM _cte_c;
```

(I know that this very query does not really make sense in terms of the common table expressions, but just let it be my desired output.)

Using SQLAlchemy's `selectables`, my code looks like this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

cte_a = sa.select(
    [sa.column('x')]
).select_from(some_table).cte('_cte_a')

cte_b = sa.select(
    [sa.column('x')]
).select_from(next_table).cte('_cte_b')

cte_c = sa.union_all(cte_a, cte_b).cte('_cte_c')

# Query with session context; unavailable before.
query = session.query('*').select_from(cte_c)
```

But the generated output is:

```
WITH
_cte_a AS (SELECT x FROM some_table),
_cte_b AS (SELECT x FROM some_table),
_cte_c AS
    SELECT x FROM _cte_a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x FROM _cte_b
SELECT *
FROM _cte_c;
```

**Note the missing parentheses around the CTE definition in the query result.** For some reason, SQLAlchemy refuses to create them when building the query part for a CTE that contains a `CompoundSelect` object as its element.

I found a solution to a similar problem that proposes using `session.query(...).subquery()` and then combining their respective results using `sa.union_all(...)`, but as I do not have the session available, I cannot follow this approach.

I've tried like all possibilities (using `alias()`, enforcing parens using `order_by()`, and many more) but nothing yields the desired result. I even replaced `SQLCompiler.visit_compound_select` method to enforce using parentheses (it is called recursively and does not place parens under certain circumstances).

Nothing helped, and I'm already biting my table. Maybe I am missing something very basic? I would very much appreciate it if someone of you could push me into the correct direction.

**Edit:** Also tried `select()` on the inner CTEs before `UNION`ing them, still no success. Even when I nest the `UNION` deeper into selects, the result remains the same.

**Edit (2):** This is really weird. Breaking down my (rather complex) original code to a MWE, the parentheses have switched. Now, they are missing for regular CTEs, but are available for the UNION'ed one:

```
meta = sa.MetaData()
t_some = sa.Table('some_table', meta, sa.Column('x', sa.Integer))
t_next = sa.Table('next_table', meta, sa.Column('x', sa.Integer))

cte_a = sa.select([
    t_some.c.x.label('x')
]).select_from(
    t_some
).cte('_cte_a')

cte_b = sa.select([
    t_next.c.x.label('x')
]).select_from(
    t_next
).cte('_cte_b')

cte_c = sa.select([
    sa.column('x')
]).select_from(
    sa.union_all(
        cte_a, cte_b
    )
).cte('_cte_c')

query = session.query(
    sa.select([sa.column('x')]).select_from(cte_c)
).order_by(
    sa.column('x').asc()
)
print(query)
```

... yields the query:

```
WITH _cte_a AS 
SELECT some_table.x AS x 
FROM some_table, 
_cte_b AS 
SELECT next_table.x AS x 
FROM next_table, 
_cte_c AS 
(SELECT x 
FROM (_cte_a UNION ALL _cte_b))
 SELECT x AS x 
FROM (SELECT x 
FROM _cte_c) ORDER BY x ASC
```

Note that now the parentheses are missing for `_cte_a` and `_cte_b`.

I really feel like I am missing something *very* basic here...

Comment: Have you tried `cte_c = sa.union_all(cte_a.select(), cte_b.select()).cte('_cte_c')`?

Comment: I did, still no parentheses. I'm sorry that I wasn't able anymore to note down all things I've tried, but this one is among them. No matter how deep I nest the `UNION` into other selects before making a CTE from them: The result is always the same.

Comment: I think that at this point you'll have to provide `some_table` and `next_table` as well, and how exactly you're getting that query output. In other words produce a [mcve], something others should be able to just copy & paste and observe your results. As to why I inquired if you've used the selects, a CTE instance is a kind of a table, and UNION expects queries as operands.

Comment: The docs http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all say that `union_all` requires `Select` instances, as generated using `sa.select(...)` :/

Comment: I meant query in the general sense of the word, but it is a bit misleading in this context. So yeah, a Select is what you should be passing to core unions. The Query API has analogous methods for Query instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some unnecessarily verbose constructs and the `union_all()` call is wrong, which seems to throw the compiler off. Instead of `CTE` instances pass it `Select` instances. You'd also usually pass `Session.query()` entities to select, not queries:

```
In [57]: cte_a = select([t_some.c.x]).cte('cte_a')

In [58]: cte_b = select([t_next.c.x]).cte('cte_b')

In [59]: cte_c = select([cte_a.c.x]).union_all(select([cte_b.c.x])).cte('cte_c')

In [60]: session.query(cte_c.c.x).order_by(cte_c.c.x)
Out[60]: <sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query at 0x7f7a5998e400>

In [61]: print(_)
WITH cte_a AS 
(SELECT some_table.x AS x 
FROM some_table), 
cte_b AS 
(SELECT next_table.x AS x 
FROM next_table), 
cte_c AS 
(SELECT cte_a.x AS x 
FROM cte_a UNION ALL SELECT cte_b.x AS x 
FROM cte_b)
 SELECT cte_c.x AS cte_c_x 
FROM cte_c ORDER BY cte_c.x
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I messed up the `union_all` calls and had to feed them with actual `Select`s, not the raw CTEs.